# Alternative word for "honed"

Tags: word-choice

Is there another word describing the process where you've polished your skills through experience - apart from "honed".  I don't think it's the best word somehow.

Comment: What's wrong with your own word ***polished***? Or you could just check a dictionary definition of ***honed***, which in almost every case would probably list the alternative ***sharpened***.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The expectation here, as throughout StackExchange, is that you do some preliminary research before posing your question. Have you consulted a thesaurus, for example?

Comment: of course I have!

Comment: Thanks FF. Sharpened is good, though not appropriate in the context of through my work at "I honed my communication skills." If you see what I mean?

Comment: One's skills might be a bit ... unpolished and dull ... if they can't recognize what native speakers would consider after sharpening or polishing through active use.

Comment: Thanks SrJoven! Definitely. Your words - unpolished and dull - describe the opposite! I am thinking of a word more like "cultivated" or "refined", even "enhanced". I find sharpened is appropriate for concrete things. Not just for pencils. But imagine if I said I sharpened my Italian this summer! I enriched and improved it!  This has been fun.  Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

Refine? Cultivate? Improve? Foster?